# Are django signals always synchronous?

Tags: python, django, queue, signals

I'm developing a django IPN plugin that saves IPN data to a model and then calls a post_save signal.

I'm worried that under this use case (gunicorn, gevent, etc) that the signals may be called/completed  asynchronously. The IPN often sends more than 1 request to the ipn url, and I need to be able to process those requests in order.

**Should I use a queue for this? Would simple python queue's work better, or should I use something like kombu + celery (with 1 worker)?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure synchronicity is your real concern here. Django's signals are always executed *in-process*: that is, they will be executed by the process that did the rest of that request, before returning a response. However, if your server itself is asynchronous, there's a possibility that one request will finish processing after a second one that was received later, and therefore the signals will be processed in the wrong order.

Celery, of course, is definitely asynchronous, but might well be a better bet if reliable ordering is a priority for you.

Comment: Just confirming what I thought, thanks! The reason synchronicity is an issue is that transactions almost always send more than one notification (different products, extra for recurring, etc). I want to be able to handle account creation with the signals, and I don't want any transactions to fall through the cracks if a model fails to save. Or worse, two accounts being created for a user.