# Django signals: how is it implemented

Tags: python, django, events

I would like to understand how Django implements signals. The only way I can imagine that it would work is that every Django application lives in an event loop and that signals trigger callbacks into action. I've done quite a number of searches online and on SO but nothing comes up. Could someone please give a detailed explanation on this? I've learned more Python from Django and I'm sure this is another opportunity.

Thanks.

polarise

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731349/are-django-signals-always-synchronous) might help.

Comment: The point, as I mention in that linked answer, is that signals are not asynchronous as OP seems to be assuming. So there's no need for any event loop; functions just call the signal registry when they want to emit a signal, and the registered signals are then called in turn.

Comment: Thanks for the above. At least one thing you have clarified is that signals are not asynchronous. However, I would appreciate a bit more detail. Thank you.