# How to know when chained django lifecycle hooks/signals are finished running?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, async-await, django-signals

I have an `Animal` model and a `Herd` model that looks like this:

```
from django_lifecycle.hooks import AFTER_CREATE

class Animal(models.Model):
    parent = OneToOneField("self", related_name="child")
    age = IntegerField()

class Herd(models.Model):
    animal = OneToOneField(Animal)
    total_age = IntegerField()
    
    @hook(AFTER_CREATE)
    def create_animal_child(self):
        if self.animal.child.exists():
            Herd.objects.create(parent=self, animal=self.animal.child)

    def save_total_age(self):
        total_age = self.animal.age
        position = self.animal
        while position.child.exists():
            total_age += position.child.age
            position = position.child
```

The idea being that you create your `Animal`s. Then you create your `Herd` for the topmost animal you want. The Herd's `AFTER_CREATE`will then create a "chain" of all the `Herd` objects for the `Animal`'s children, the children's children, and so on.

E.g.

```
a1 = Animal.objects.create(age=10)
a2 = Animal.objects.create(parent=a1, age=7)
a3 = Animal.objects.create(parent=a2, age=3)

h1 = Herd.objects.create(animal=a1)
# Two Herd objects with an "animal" field pointing to a2 and a3 respectively are automatically created

h1.save_total_age() # h1.total_age = 20 # 10 + 7 + 3
```

Which is all fine.

My problem is for my front-end, how can I tell when all the relevant `Animal` `AFTER_CREATE` hooks have finished running so I know to call my `calculate_total_age` method?

So say I have the following REST API endpoints:

```
example.com/api/animals/<pk>
example.com/api/herds/<pk>
example.com/api/herds/<pk>/save_total_age
```

If I do a POST to `example.com/api/herds/<pk>` to create a `Herd`, I call `save_total_age()` as soon as that "parent" `Herd` is created - and not necessarily after all the "children" `Herd`s have been created via the `AFTER_CREATE` hook.

```
axios.post(
    "example.com/api/herds/",
    {animal_id: 1}
).then((response) => {
    axios.post(
        `example.com/api/herds/${response.data.pk}/save_total_age`,
        {},
    )
});
```

How can I set my backend signals and/or frontend async/await so that `save_total_age()` only runs *after* my `AFTER_CREATE` chain is complete?

Edit: My best solution right now is to add some condition to `save_word_count()` that makes sure the `Herd` chain has the same # of objects as the `Animal` chain. If so, run the method. If not, return a bad request and retry the POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signals (which are called by those hooks) run synchronously, not asynchronously. So when you call `create()` for your first heard, it will always run the `AFTER_CREATE` hook and create the 2nd Heard object, before it returns and let you run the `save_total_age()` method.

In other words this should work just fine as it is.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is true for signal "chains" as well? So creating Herd 1 will also create Herd 2, 3, etc. all the way before returning the 2XX code for Herd 1? I've tried searching for this but I can't find anything... can you point me towards any documentation?

Comment: yes. signal chains are called just like any ordinary function chain. those calls are synchronous within the current request. see also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731349/are-django-signals-always-synchronous